# Deployment Error of shiny app on shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to deploy a shiny app on shiny server, I get this error, Any idea about this error?

```
Building with AppArmor (Linux)
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lapparmor
On Debian/Ubuntu this package requires AppArmor.
Please run: sudo apt-get install libapparmor-dev
To build without AppArmor support, set NO_APPARMOR=1 for example:
install.packages('sys', configure.vars = 'NO_APPARMOR=1')
ERROR: configuration failed for package �sys�
* removing �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sys�
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 428423284 failed: Error building image: Error building sys (1.3). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
Execution halted
```

Comment: Please don't post errors as images. This is at this time, not searchable. Please show the text. Also, what does the internet say about the error? Are you perhaps missing a package?

Comment: I added the text to the post

Comment: Perhaps run `sudo apt-get install libapparmor-dev`?

Comment: found the problem! when I removed the file that contains "readText" package from the deployment, it worked fine